# How to create jobs on Jenkins with credentials enabled?

Tags: c#, build, jenkins

I have code to create/update jobs on Jenkins without credentials enabled.

```
const string FORMAT = "http://{0}:{1}/createItem?name={2}";
var path =
    string.Format(
        FORMAT,
        this.config.JenkinsServer,
        this.config.JenkinsPort,
        buildName);

this.http.UploadString(
    path,
    definition,
    new Header(HttpRequestHeader.ContentType, "text/xml"));
```

Now, I want to move one step forward by enable credentials and specify username/password when creating a new job. I found [an article about Authenticating scripted clients on Jenkins](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Authenticating+scripted+clients) but there is no code example in C# and couldn't figure it out how to do it.

How to create/update jobs on Jenkins with credentials enabled?

**[UPDATE]**
Specify username and password on the url like in [this link](http://benkiew.wordpress.com/2012/01/12/automating-hudsonjenkins-via-rest-and-curl-a-very-small-cookbook/) also doesn't work.

Comment: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Authenticating+scripted+clients

Answer (score 5):

You can authenticate to Jenkins using a user based AUTHTOKEN.
Get the token by going to you user configuration page.

http://{JENKINS.HOST}/user/{YOUR.USERNAME}/configure

Then click the 'Show API Token' button, and it will display a GUID as an AuthToken, which you can then use with something like the following.

```
string password = "5agbe1d6f774634169e9ba4625559bc83f";  // AKA the Jenkins AuthToken
string userName = "YOUR.USERNAME";                       // AKA your Jenkins userID

var webClient = new System.Net.WebClient();

// Create a basic auth token from a username and password seperated by a colon then base 64encoded
string basicAuthToken = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(userName + ":" + password));
webClient.Headers["Authorization"] = "Basic " + basicAuthToken;

return client.UploadString(path, definition, headers);
```

Comment: System.Net.WebClient doesn't seem to have a function called SetBasicAuthHeader for me

Comment: What version of .Net are you running

Comment: 4.5. Stack overthrow has a minimum comment length which I'm filling up.

Comment: Ahh, my bad, I must have been referring to an extension method that I'd written. I've updated the answer to reflect this